# Rmarkdown Cannot Run Chunk but Can Run in Console

Tags: r, windows, r-markdown, markdown

I'm setting up Rmarkdown in windows setting and everything **can run properly in Console,  But CANNOT run in Rmarkdown chunk**.

If I click that green little play button to run the chunk, it returns a confusing error:

[image]

FYI This is the environment:

> R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) -- "Feather Spray"

> Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing

> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

and this is the Error message:

> Error in rbind(info, getNamespaceInfo(env, "S3methods")) :   number of
> columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)

The confusing part is that there's NOTHING in my code even remotely related to rbind! Even if the entire chunk only contains "1+1" it still says "Erro in rbind"...

Comment: Did you restart R/R Studio ?

Comment: That's a very old R. It also looks as if it's something weird to do with a built S3methods package. I wonder if your installation has problems.

Answer (score 1):

After connecting with the rmarkdown package developer we found out that this is due to the R version issue. I was on 3.5.1. But you need to be on 3.6.2!
[GITHUB ISSUE LINK](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/2117)
The issue resolved by uninstalling R 3.5.1 and reinstalling R 3.6.2
Also, since I don't have admin access to my laptop, I had to run install.package("###", type = "binary")
All the best,
Kathy